# Isolated points in a complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

I need to prove that if $X$ is a countable (infinite) complete metric space, then $X$ has infinitely many isolated points.

I have read that the Baire Category theorem implies that $X$ should have at least one isolated point, but I have no idea how to show the set of isolated points is infinite.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hint: Remove an isolated point from a complete metric space. Does it remain  complete? Now, think about induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that it has a finite number of isolated points $x_1,..,x_n$, $Y=X-\{x_1,..,x_n\}$ is still complete. Every element $y\in Y$ as an empty interior. You can write $Y=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{y_n\}$, Baire implies that $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{y_n\}=Y$ has an empty interior. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [as Moishe points out in the comments above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172190/isolated-points-in-a-complete-metric-space#comment6531125_3172190), if $X$ has only finitely-many isolated points, then we can remove them all, and obtain a complete, countably-infinite metric space (say $Y$) with *no* isolated points.

But this is impossible! Let $f:\Bbb N\to Y$ be a bijection, and consider the sets $O_n:=Y\setminus\bigl\{f(n)\bigr\}.$ Each $O_n$ is open (obviously) and dense (since $f(n)$ is not isolated in $Y$), so since $Y$ is a complete metric space, then BCT tells us that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}O_n$ is dense in $Y,$ but this is absurd, since $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}O_n=\emptyset.$

Comment: It helped me to work instead with Baire Category theorem with the Corollary: If $(U_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is any sequence of dense subsets of a complete metric space $X$. then the $G_\delta$-set $E=\cap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: @user2820579 That's exactly the result I used, but I didn't make that very clear. Hopefully it makes more sense now!

Comment: Yes, no problem. My point was just to say that usually Baire's theorem is stated as "If $X$ is a complete metric space and $E$ a residual in $X$, then $E$ is dense in $X$". There's no explicit mention of the dense open sets, so I just felt it would be nice to complement the answer with a concrete statement.